# How does the amount of liquid in a cylindrical can affect its motion when rolling down an inclined plane?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

How does the amount of liquid in a cylindrical can affect its motion when rolling down an inclined plane?

Comment: Maybe you could see this question : [Rotational Motion down an inclined plane](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/211614/doubt-related-to-rotational-motion-rolling-down-an-inclined-plane). Also, this site could help : [Rolling Race](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/rolling-race). This pdf is also a relevant read: [Effects of a fluid in a can rolling down an incline](http://physics.wooster.edu/JrIS/Files/Rosch_Web_Article.pdf).

Comment: If you see the formula given, acceleration will be constant for a particular body with a defined MI as well as a constant mass, right? Acceleration is the slope for a v-t plot, it has to be constant for a particular body.

Comment: R is the radius of the cylinder. It has to be constant, otherwise, the object won't even be a cylinder at multiple instances of time. Why will it change?

Comment: Again, the Rotational Inertia (or the Moment of Inertia) for a particular case doesn't change, since the object is the same, the amount of water is the same and also, the axis about which the cylinder is rotating is the same.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I didn't think it through before writing. Moment of Inertia of any body depends on the mass distribution as well(The radius of gyration also depends on the distribution of the mass).

Comment: Is this going to be a very viscous fluid, or is it going to be like water?  Do you think that the liquid is going to be rotating as a rigid body, or is there a viscous boundary layer that builds up on the perimeter, while the bulk of the liquid does not rotate?

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with water, then it will behave nearly like an inviscid fluid, meaning that, aside from a very thin boundary layer near the wall, the fluid will not be rotating as the can rolls down the incline.  Basically treating the water as inviscid is equivalent to allowing the water to slip at the wall.  This would prevent the can rotation from propagating into the fluid.  So the water would move down the incline as a non-rotating body while the can would rotate around it (and would have rotational inertia).  The problem could be modeled that way.

A very highly viscous fluid, on the other hand, would behave as a rigid body stuck to the wall whose center of mass is offset from the axis.  It would be possible to model this situation also.

Another situation that might not be too hard to analyze would be a moderately viscous fluid that fills the can.

However, other situations would be pretty difficult to get a handle on.  For example, the case of a moderately viscous fluid that does not fill the can.

In my judgment the range of possibilities of % fill and fluid viscosity is too broad to be tractable right now.  I think you need to narrow the range of possibilities that you are willing to consider.

Comment: I would use either a full can with fluids of different viscosities or an partially filled can with a low viscosity fluid, like water, with different degrees of fill.